# Adding a new node to the existing Kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes, centos, etcd

I have an K8S cluster running with 6 nodes 1 Master and 5 minion nodes running on baremetal.
I wanted to add a new minion node which i tried testing the procedure in VM and was succesfull the new node joining the cluster multiple times.
However i have a question which i wanted to get clarified.

In general we first need to bring the etcd service up which the new node should join the existing etcd cluster.

Afetr installing the needed files on the new minion node and adding the new node details + the existing node under /etc/etcd/etcd.conf file and making the INITIAL_CLUSTER_STATE to set to "EXISTING".
Then we will add the command etcdctl add member

My question is that on other existing nodes (Master and minion) do we need to add the new node details in the /etc/etcd/etcd.conf file or it is not required ?

Atleast during the testing on the VM's i remember that unless i add the new node details in the existing nodes the etcd service on new node is not up completely.But i see the docs related to etcd adding new member it is not mentioned anywhere about the adding of new node details in the existing nodes under the file /etc/etcd/etcd.conf ..
Can someone let me know if this file to be modified in existing nodes and update with new node details ?

Comment: What have you used to setup kubernetes cluster? Kubeadm?

Comment: No.. I mean it was on RedHat Atomic Host Cent OS..So Once the OS is installed configuring the services etcd,flanneld,docker and kubelet to make sure all are up and running..Kind of manual procedure or play-books to update these files as required.

Answer (score 0):

If you are adding new minion node you don't need to setup or configure etcd on the new minion. You need to setup Kubelet and kube proxy services and network service

Comment: No.. I am running a baremetal cluster .. and the services are etcd,flanneld,docker,kubelet and kube-proxy...They are depandent each other..first etcd to be configured and flannel depends on etcd,docker depends on flannel,kubelet and kube-proxy depends on docker..so etcd is mandate in this case

Comment: Api server which is a component of control pane communicates with etcd. Minions don't connect directly to etcd. All connections go through api server. You don't need to setup etcd service on minion. However, you might need etcd address from Master for minion setup

Comment: Yes.. but here is the sample of etcd service running on the minion node..-bash-4.2# systemctl status etcd
● etcd.service - Etcd Server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/etcd.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
  Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/etcd.service.d
           └─restart.conf
   Active: active (running) since Wed 2016-06-22 17:17:58 CEST; 2 years 7 ..So i need to have the etcd service as here up and running on my new minion node.To get this do i need to add the new node details in the /etc/etcd/etcd.conf file in the Master ?

Comment: -bash-4.2# cat /etc/etcd/etcd.conf
# [member]
ETCD_NAME="kamesh"
ETCD_DATA_DIR="/var/lib/etcd/kamesh.etcd"
ETCD_LISTEN_PEER_URLS="http://10.x.y.z:2380"
ETCD_LISTEN_CLIENT_URLS="http://127.0.0.1:2379,http://10.x.y.z:2379"
#[cluster]
ETCD_INITIAL_ADVERTISE_PEER_URLS="http://10.x.y.z:2380"
ETCD_INITIAL_CLUSTER="node-01=http://10.x.y.z:2380,node-02=http://10.x.y.z:2380,node-03=http://10.x.y.z:2380,node-04=http://10.x.y.z:2380,node-05=http://10.x.y.z:2380,node-06=http://10.x.y.z:2380"
ETCD_INITIAL_CLUSTER_STATE="new"
ETCD_INITIAL_CLUSTER_TOKEN="somevalue"

Comment: So i gave sample output of etcd.conf file and do i need to add my new node details in ETC_INITIAL_ADVERTISE_PEER_URLS section for the master node and other nodes as well is my question ?

Comment: No. Etcd is needed only for masters. If you are setting up etcd in high availability, 3 etcd instances, then you need use that etcd advertise  peer aram